# Segmentation fault in Linked list /C

Tags: c, linked-list

I wanna remove the last item from my linkedlist, but become an Segmentation-fault. So some pointer is wrong. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listenElement{
    int wert;
    struct listenElement *next;
};
static  struct listenElement* anfang = NULL;
int removeElement(void) {
    if (anfang == NULL){     
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        int l = NULL;
        struct listenElement *p = anfang->next ;     
        if (p->next == NULL){
            l = p->wert;
            free(p);
            anfang->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while(p->next != NULL){
              anfang = p;
              p = p->next;
              l = p->wert;
              free(p);
            }
            anfang =p;
            anfang->next= NULL;
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always format your code before letting others see it.

Comment: Your `while` loop is wrong, it frees `p`, but then you access it with `p->next` or `anfang=p; anfang->next=NULL;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note once you have called free on some pointer you can't access that pointer (memory via other pointer also), doing this calls undefined behavior—it is an illegal memory instruction that can be detected at runtime that may causes — a segmentation fault as well:

Following code is wrong:

```
while(p->next!=NULL){// <--+  you use `p` - that is invalid 
    anfang = p;    //      |
    p = p->next;   //      |
    l = p->wert;   //      |
    free(p);//-------------+  you free `p`
}
```

Additionally learn [Indenting C Programs](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html).

There are some more mistakes in your code:

1. Logic is incorrect, you don't consider the case when there is only one node present. You need to add,

   ```
    // this first pice of code to add
    // Case-1: when nodes in linked list are = 1
   if (anfang->next == NULL){
      free(anfang);
      anfang = NULL; reset to NULL   
      return 1; // as you returns 
    }
   ```
2. You while loop can be improved and the use of `anfang` in loop and after loop is wrong. `anfang` should point to first node always, you just need to remove last node. And if there are more than one node in linked list then `anfang` value doesn't change (read comments):

   ```
    // this code should be after above code
    // Case-2: when nodes in linked list are > 1
    p = anfang;  // 
    last = anfang->next; // last node
    // a loop for travel to reach - last node in linked list
    while(last->next != NULL){//stop when last - points to last node
       p = last;      // every time before update last make `p` the `last`
       last = last->next;
    }
    p->next = NULL; // make `p` as last node, to remove last node
    free(last);  // free memory for last node
   ```

Logically you where wrong, In your code you call free within while loop whereas your objective is to remove just one—the last node.

Comment: A very good answer. I also think the use of the variable `anfang` seems wrong, you might want to include something about it too.

Comment: @kviiri I direct target at seg-fault, there are more mistakes also I add in my answer thanks

Comment: Did you try to understand my answer? Did you write rest of the code yourself? Anyways complete `removeElement(void)` function should look like this [**click here**](http://codepad.org/JVRehk2d)

Comment: @user3578012 You can "add comment", check [this link](http://codepad.org/JVRehk2d)

Comment: @user3578012 You should add declarations for `last` and `p` inside function definition as I added in the [linked code](http://codepad.org/JVRehk2d).